# errorjava.sql.SQLException: Column 'pts' not found

Tags: java, sql, select, jdbc

This is the table that I have:
table name: player. all data type are float

```
id      | pts  | gp
0       | 45   | 5
1       | 13   | 6
2       | 74   | 10
```

I want to select the avg of the points. here's the function i used on button click after connecting to the db.

```
public float getavgstats() {
 float ptsavg = 0;


 try {
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select (cast((pts/gp) as decimal(10,2))) as ppg from player order by ppg desc");
  while (rs.next()) {
  ptsavg = rs.getFloat("pts");
  System.out.println(ptsavg);
 }
} catch (Exception ex) {
 System.out.println("error" + ex);
}
return ptsavg;
}
}
```

I'm getting an error that the column 'pts' is not found

Comment: Your resultset doesn't contain anything else than a `ppg` field .Try `ptsavg = rs.getFloat("ppg");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns only one column - `ppg`, it doesn't have a `pts` column in it.

If you want to query it, you should add it to your query:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
    "select pts, (cast((pts/gp) as decimal(10,2))) as ppg " +
    // Here-^
    "from player order by ppg desc");
```